# How to set name of the test namespace to run in xunit.console

Tags: xunit.net

nunit-console has "/run" option to run a specific test fixture or namespace to run:

```
$nunit-console FooTest.dll -run:FooTest.BarTest
Execution Runtime: net-3.5
Selected test(s): FooTest.BarTest
.
Tests run: 1, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.03125 seconds
```

There is an equivalent option in xunit.console.exe?

Answer (score 0):

I could say I dunno but here are some ideas:-

1. the console runner's source is on codeplex and is very readable and very small
2. There's a `TraitAttribute` mechanism that allows one to tag and then filter in or out by tag
3. There's an xunit.runner.tdnet.dll on codeplex which does offer these constructs
4. The xunit forum is more likely to net you a good answer for this sort of question